# Solana JSON RPC error 32015: Transaction version (0) not supported

Tags: python, jsonrpc-api

I am trying to use the Solana JSON RPC to request the data from blocks using get_block.  I've been using this a bunch just fine but have started to get an error that I don't understand, and can't find any explanation for.

The request is:

[{'jsonrpc': '2.0',
'id': 1,
'method': 'getBlock',
'params': [150059418,
{'encoding': 'json', 'transactionDetails': 'full', 'rewards': False}]}]

I'm using the python requests module to post it:

resp = requests.post(dev_client_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(request_vec))

where the headers are just {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

the response code is 200

but it has an error:
[{'jsonrpc': '2.0',
'error': {'code': -32015,
'message': 'Transaction version (0) is not supported'},
'id': 1}]

What does this even mean?  This is a valid block https://solscan.io/block/150059418?cluster=devnet and the error seems reproducible, as I can just submit that request now and it fails with that error.

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!  Full minimum working example below:

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
import json as json

data_vec = [{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'method': 'getBlock', 'params': [150059418, {'encoding': 'json', 'transactionDetails': 'full', 'rewards': False}]}]

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

dev_client_url ="https://api.devnet.solana.com"


resp = requests.post(dev_client_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data_vec))

print(resp.json())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be some forthcoming communications and documentation from the devrel team this week on the matter but for now, know that you'll need to add support for v0 transactions to your consumer service and pass the `maxSupportedTransactionVersion` option to [`getBlock`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblock).

The gist on v0 transactions is that they add support for "Address Lookup Table accounts" which allow for referencing more accounts than would typically fit withing the serialized size limit. Two new fields will need to be handled when `.version == 0`

- From `getBlock` the `.transactions[].meta.loadedAddresses` field lists additional `.writable` and `.readonly` addresses that have been loaded from address lookup table accounts.  They extend the `.transactions[].message.accountKeys` field by concatenation.  That is

  ```
  tx = .transactions[index];
  tx.message.accountKeys | tx.meta.loadedAddresses.writable | tx.meta.loadedAddresses.readonly
  ```

  Account indexes within `Instructions` then point into this total concatenated list.
- `Transaction` objects from both `getBlock` and `getTransaction` now also have a `.message.addressTableLookups` object, which is a mapping of which Lookup Table Account specified which addresses in `.meta.loadedAddresses`

Comment: Without checking for the presence of an account loader ix via sysvar instructions, would there be / is there an idiomatic way to get transaction version during program runtime in the rust solana_program?

Comment: Thanks for this.  Can i just check something.  Right now I am using the programIdIndex in each instruction of the transaction  to check whether that instruction interacted with our program.  will that index still only refer to the message["accountKeys"] node for a v0 transaction, or do i need to handle the readable/writable nodes myself.

Comment: new question -> new post

Comment: "The gist on v0 transactions is that they add" - this is confusing. What was the version before version 0?